# How do I repair Microsoft .NET Framework in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, .net-framework

I tried to manually uninstall Visual Studio Community Edition with a 3rd party program (Total Uninstall). Now when I run some .NET programs, I get the following error:

> Please set registry key
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework\InstallRoot to point to the .NET
>   Framework install location

Troubleshoting tried so far:

- Re-install .NET Framework 4.6.2--the installer tells me ".NET Framework X.X.X or a later update is already installed on this computer."
- Use Microsoft's .NET Framework Repair Tool--it runs successfully, but the issue remains.
- Used "sfc /scannow"--process runs successfully, but the issue remains.
- Re-installed the Visual C++ Redistributables, 2008, 2010, and 2013--all ran successfully, but the issue remains.
- Ran DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth--ran successfully, but still have the issue.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this link to manually remove the .Net framework https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/908077

Comment: 1)  This is the exact reason you should not use third-party software to remove software.  Programs like Total Uninstall, are snake oil, they don't do anything helpful that the Add/Remove Program functionality does not do already.  2) Have you tried the [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/)?  The use of this tool will wipe everything that is .NET Framework on your system.  You will have to add Windows Feature back to your ssytem, after you run it, be sure you try adding and removing the Windows Feature though.

Comment: Have you considered using a registry cleaner to get rid of the bad registry entries?  It sounds like you've got a legacy registry entry that is still being used.  I'd recommend [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com).  It's free, and it may help resolve the issue.

Comment: @Ramhound, I see what you mean, and no, I will never, ever use that product (or anything similar) again.

I tried the .NET Framework Cleanup Tool, and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @vembutech, thank you, but that page is for .NET 2.0, which was never installed on my system.

Comment: Can you go through your entire question again, attempt to clarify anything you might have left out, there is something causing this problem.  Have you tried to add and remove the windows feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried everything. I again tried the .NET Framework clean-up tool, but this didn't resolve the situation, so I ended up doing a System Refresh. Yes, this meant I had to re-install all of the programs that I wanted on the system, but all other methods failed.

So the lessons we learned from this adventure?
* Don't use third-party uninstallation products without knowing what software can, and cannot, be removed from your system.
* It is possible to refresh Windows 8.1 without losing your files.

I hope this will be of use to others with similar problems.